# Wage Equations: Extracting from a schooling dummy years of schooling

Tags: stata

I'm running wage equations and have in my data only highest level of education attained which takes the values of 1, 2 and 3. I am trying to calculate the mean years of schooling and standard deviation per occupational group, for which I will need years of schooling as a continuous variable. I have estimates re: years of schooling associated with each level of schooling, but not sure how I can make the transfer from educational levels to years of schooling whilst ensuring the same weights. Any ideas using Stata?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by weight? Complex sample weight?

Comment: Weights is the wrong word. More like the percentage shares associated with each level of education. the invcdf function in stata seems to address this though i'm still not sure about converting levels of educational attainment to years of schooling.

Comment: Stata focus would make this off-topic. Let's hope that the small amount of Stata here doesn't obscure the statistical content.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a variable `educ`, which is

- 1 when someone has less than highschool,
- 2 when someone has highschool,
- 3 when someone has some college, and
- 4 when someone finished college.

You want to assign:

- 10 years of schooling to someone with less than highschool,
- 12 years of schooling to someone with highschool,
- 14 years of schooling to someone with some college, and
- 16 years of schooling to someone with finished college

Then you type in Stata:

```
recode educ (1=10) (2=12) (3=14) (4=16), gen(educyr)
label variable educyr "respondent's education in pseudo-years"
```

Comment: Thanks Maarten. I guess what I was trying to do was more recode educ (1=0/10) (2=11/14) (3=15/23), gen(educyr) which doesn't work.

Comment: Say we have a person with highschool. What is Stata supposed to give that person when you execute your command? 11, 12, 13, or 14 years of schooling? Stata is a computer program, so it will do exactly what you tell it. If what you tell it is ambiguous, like in the example where it is unknown which number of years to assign to a person, it will return an error.

Comment: Also, looks like `gen educyr = 8 + 2 * educ` to me. If linear recoding is adopted, simply note that the original variable would also do fine, although I am happy with a preference that coefficients have substantive meaning.